# How to avoid showing some secret values in sparkUI

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-submit, spark-ui, redaction

I am passing some secret keys in spark-submit command.
I am using below to redact the key:
--conf 'spark.redaction.regex='secret_key'

though it is working,the secret_key is visible in sparkUI during job execution.The redaction takes place at the end.How to avoid this?